# How to transform XDocument leaving only selected paths?

Tags: c#, xml

I have a lot of (millions) xml documents ranging from small to large. I have a requirement to process(transform) them by c#7 leaving only some paths (paths may vary; they will be set by user).

Sample of one document (I do not care about namespaces at the moment):

```
<root>
<a><aa1></aa1><aa2></aa2></a>
<b><bb></bb></b>
<c><cc></cc></c>
<d>d</d>
</root>
```

Given `/root/a/aa1` and `/root/d` are white listed I should produce this result:

```
<root>
<a><aa1></aa1></a>
<d>d</d>
</root>
```

I guess that the best way is to specify whitelist paths as a collection of XPath expressions.

Existing processing loads xmls into XDocuments.

I can select necessary elements by `XPathSelectElements`. The question is: how to copy them to new XDocument?

Alternatively I may delete all siblings of selected elements. How to perform that deletion?

Performance and memory footprint should be taken into consideration.

Comment: Take a look at XSLT, there should be plenty examples on how to do it via C#.

Comment: @MichaelDaniloff xslt will be my last resort as its identity transfrom is becoming pia if you care about namespaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will perform the deletion of non-whitelisted nodes thus compressing the XML document:

```
/// <summary> Siblings including self </summary>
public static IEnumerable<XElement> Siblings(this XElement xml) =>
    xml?.Parent?.Elements() ?? new List<XElement>();

/// <summary> Ancestors, descendants and self </summary>
public static IEnumerable<XElement> AncestorsDescendantsSelf(this XElement xml) =>
    xml?.DescendantsAndSelf()?.Union(xml?.Ancestors() ?? new List<XElement>()) ?? new List<XElement>();

/// <summary> Compress the document by removing everything except the elemnents along selected paths </summary>
/// <param name="xml">source document to be modified</param>
/// <param name="whitelistedPaths">collection of xpath paths</param>
public static void Compress(this XDocument xml, IEnumerable<string> whitelistedPaths) {
    var siblings = nodes.SelectMany(n => n.AncestorsAndSelf()).Aggregate((new List<XElement>()).AsEnumerable(), (n1,n2) => n1.Union(n2.Siblings()));
    var lineages = nodes.SelectMany(n => n.AncestorsDescendantsSelf());
    var nodesToDelete = siblings.Except(lineages).ToList();
    foreach (var element in nodesToDelete) {
        element.Remove();
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** That this code is far from fast/perfect but it just works.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following algorithm:

(a) expand the given set of paths to include all prefixes of these paths, so from (`/root/a/aa1`, `/root/d`) you get (`/root`, `/root/a`, `/root/a/aa1`, `/root/d`)

(b) from this set of paths generate an XSLT stylesheet where (i) the default template rule does a deep-skip (`<xsl:template match="*"/>`), and (ii) the template rule for each of the given paths does a shallow copy (`<xsl:copy><xsl:copy-of select="@*"/><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:copy>`).

(c) run this generated stylesheet over the source document.

You may find it useful that in XPath 3.1/XSLT 3.0 you can handle namespace-sensitive paths using the EQName notation, for example match="Q{some-uri}root/Q{some-uri}a". With earlier XPath versions, handling paths referring to namespaced element names is always a problem. This applies equally to non-XSLT solutions.

Comment: thx, that's a good idea. I have tried a variation of it already and failed. I have tried to dynamicaly expand paths inside template's match attrib using ancestor and descendant axis. Xml spy said it is a wrong syntax(